# Wordpress rewrite rule redirects to post

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm currently messing around with URL rewriting within Wordpress.

I'm trying to rewrite this URL:

http://localhost/adorable-nails/behandelingen-tarieven/?category=gelnagels

To:

http://localhost/adorable-nails/behandelingen-tarieven/gelnagels

I added the following code to my theme's functions.php:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "category";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^behandelingen-tarieven/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=behandelingen-tarieven&category=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

So what seems to be happening is when i try to go to http://localhost/adorable-nails/behandelingen-tarieven/gelnagels it redirects me to a post that has "gelnagels" in te postname, my current permalink settings are set to: http://localhost/adorable-nails/sample-post/

So what i'm wondering is there anyway to avoid the redirect, or do i have to pick the plain permalink settings and do all rewrite rules myself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your regex has 2 possible matches and the url provided just one. Changing `^behandelingen-tarieven/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?` to `^behandelingen-tarieven/([^/]*)/?` and saving your permalinks config does solve your problem?

Comment: I've written an answer. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex has 2 possible matches and the url provided just one. Changing `^behandelingen-tarieven/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?` to `^behandelingen-tarieven/([^/]*)/?` and saving your permalinks seemed solved the problem.

The most important thing here (and that's why I'm writting this as an answer) is:

**Never forget saving your permalinks config after changing a rewrite_rule**

I've spent too much time changing it and nothing happened until I realize that saving the permalinks were necessary. Hope this helps someone in the future :)